svelteKit with bootstrap
currently I'm learning sveltekit, and I install bootstrap and icons to. This is my package.json:
    "devDependencies": {
        "@sveltejs/adapter-auto": "^3.0.0",
        "@sveltejs/kit": "^2.0.0",
        "@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte": "^3.0.0",
        "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
        "svelte": "^4.2.7",
        "vite": "^5.0.3"
    },
    "type": "module",
    "dependencies": {
        "bootstrap": "^5.3.3",
        "bootstrap-icons": "^1.11.3",
        "simple-datatables": "^9.0.3"
    }

on file src/routes/+layout.svelte
<script>
  import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
  import NavBar from '../components/nav/navBar.svelte';
  import SideBar from '../components/nav/sideBar.svelte'
  import '../css/style.css'

</script>

<div> 
    <NavBar />
    <SideBar /> 
    <main id="main" class="main">
      <slot /> 
    </main>     
</div>

and on my file src/+page.svelte
<i class="bi bi-heart-fill"></i>
<p>Hi</p>

and checking on the proyect run, I don't see the icon:

and checking on the DevTools I see the tag, so what's wrong?

I don't see any import from bootstrap-icons?

I got you!!! I add this line   import 'bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css'; and ready, thanks bro!
